# list index out of range processing CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, list

I have a file, score.csv; it has 13320 rows and 3 columns - the columns are 'timestamp','Score', and'label'.

I want to manipulate my data block by block, with each block consisting of 360 rows. If I have (score > 0.5 and label == 1) then count = 1 (it is not necessary to manipulate all the blocks if I get 1) and the program skips to the next block of 360 rows.

I have this error: "list index out of range"

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dataSet, columns = 
 ['timestamp','Score','label'] )
 L=[]
 x=0
 for y,row in  df.iterrows():
   data=  row.to_dict() 
   Score=data['Score']
   label=data['label']
   L.append((Score,label))

 for i in range (0,len(L),360):
     x=x+1

    for j in range(i,360*x):

       if((L[j][0] >=0.4) and L[j][1]==1):
          TruePostive=TruePostive+1
          print("the TruePostive is in block number" ,x)

       if((L[j][0] < 0.4) and L[j][1]==1):
          TrueNegative=TrueNegative+1
          print("the TrueNegative is in block number" ,x)

       if((L[j][0] >= 0.4) and L[j][1]==0):
          FalsePositive=FalsePositive+1
          print("the FalsePositive is in block number" ,x)

       if((L[j][0] < 0.4) and L[j][1]==0):
          FalseNegative=FalsePositive+1
          print("the FalseNegative is in block number" ,x) 

  print("TruePostive=",TruePostive)
  print("TrueNegative=", TrueNegative)
  print("FalsePositive=", FalsePositive)
  print("FalseNegative=", FalseNegative)
```

Comment: Perhaps that should be `L.append((Score, label))`? Otherwise I'd have difficulty seeing how this code worked. It's not clear to me exactly what output you'd like to see.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @wissal: I've edited the post to clean up the grammar a bit. If I changed the meaning, please feel free to [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53854672/edit) yourself to clarify things.

Comment: What's the starting value of `x`? What line goes out of bounds? I suspect it is the `L[j]` access that is problematic, but it's impossible to tell given the code above...

Comment: Have you tried any trivial attempt at debugging by e.g. printing `j` and `len(L)` immediately before attempting to access `L[Jj`?

Comment: I make some changes , sorry for my language mistakes. I think now is very clear

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: this line if((L[j][0] >=0.4) and L[j][1]==1):

Comment: Do some simple debugging - print the value of i,x,j and len(L) - you can redirect output to file to see what the value of j is when the exception happens. Why is this so difficult?